# JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data (node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

the problem is the following and I can't figure it out,I built a management application with authentication system using node js / express / mongodb / jwt,
to me to all existing browsers except Mozzila Dev Edition it works,
to all users the same mostly with small exceptions where they have the same problem that I have at mozzila.

**1)I have built a function architect to block access if you are not authorized.**

```
exports.protect = catchAsync(async(req,res,next) =>{

let token;

//Get token from header authorization postman or other tools
if(req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')){
   
    token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

}else if(req.cookies.jwt){
    
    token = req.cookies.jwt;

}

if(!token){
    return next(new AppError('You are not logged in! Please log in to get access.',401));
}

//Verify token is in valid using jwt
const decoded =  await promisify(jwt.verify)(token,process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY);
//Find user in DB
const isLoggedUser = await User.findById(decoded.id);

if(!isLoggedUser){
    return next(new AppError('User not found,please try again!.',401)); 
}

//Check if user changed password after the token was issued
if(!isLoggedUser.changedPasswordAfter(decoded.iat)){
    return next(new AppError('User recently changed password! Please login again.',401)); 
}



req.user = isLoggedUser;

next();
})
```

in the other file the code looks like this **Controllercompany.js**

```
//Get Company and snopuri by staff clienti email
exports.getCompanyByEmail = catchAsync(async (req,res)=>{
const staff= req.user.email;

const findCompanyByAdress = await Company.find({staffUser:staff});

res.status(200).json({
    status:'success',
    data:findCompanyByAdress
});
});
```

the application path looks like this **routerCompany**

```
router.route('/get-company-by-staff-adress').get(authController.protect,firmeController.getCompanyByEmail);
```

In the UI I used fetch to bring the information and to create a literal template

```
const getStaffClientiData = async ()=>{

await fetch('{url}/api/v1/company//get-company-by-staff-adress').then(response => response.json()).then(results =>{
    //Get Data
    let companyRes = results.data.reverse();
    
    
        companyRes.forEach(find => {
            //Function which will render data  
            renderCompanyOptionInSidebar(find)    
        });
   

}).catch(e =>{
    console.log(e);
    showAlert('error', 'Aaparut o eroare la gasirea companiilor corespunzatoare acestui cont!!!' + e);
})
  }

  getStaffClientiData();
```

To browsers such as chrome, moziila, opera, brave, explorer work without any problem,but at mozilla dev edition I have problems there are users who have problems including chrome etc.the problems look like this.

[image]

[image]
[image]

from what I noticed it's as if sometimes the browser refuses to identify cookies,I tried to solve this **using cors**, **to set the header** in the js app, **delete the history and catch the browser**,to **delete the catch on the node server**.

```
app.use(cors({ origin:true, credentials:true }));

// Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,accept, authorization');

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
 // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});
```

I was looking for articles about HTTP2 401, someone said about deleting the catch from dns.It's something I omit but I can't figure out, maybe someone has been through this before and they have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: In your client-side fetch, you're trying to parse the response as JSON no matter what it is. You could simply check for `response.ok` first before doing that.

Comment: ok,let me try this

Comment: by the way, mixing async/await in the same function as promise .then/.catch is never good practice ... use one, or the other, (almost) never both - this isn't an almost case as the code is very basic

Comment: the same issue,there a better option to replace async/await

Comment: I didn't say replace anything nor did I say it would fix anything - just mixing those two forms of Promises is not good practice - sorry, didn't mean to confuse you

Comment: ok I undesrstoo,but the problem since to be from the server side,I get anauthorized on this browsers